# In App Purchase's SKProductsRequest not working when App is already installed on the device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, in-app-purchase

I am having problems testing the In App Purchase feature. If I reinstall the app on a device that has already installed the app with a previous version, the SKProductsRequest returns a response only with an object on the invalidProductIdentifiers. If I delete the app from the device and then install the new version again, SKProductsRequest works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)requestProductData:(NSString *)aFeatureID {    
    SLLog(@"Products Request For: %@", aFeatureID);
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:aFeatureID]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    if ([response.products count] > 0) {        
        [self.purchasableObjects addObjectsFromArray:response.products];

#ifndef NDEBUG  
        for(int i=0;i<[self.purchasableObjects count];i++)
        {       
            SKProduct *product = [self.purchasableObjects objectAtIndex:i];
            SLLog(@"Feature: %@, Cost: %f, ID: %@",[product localizedTitle],
                  [[product price] doubleValue], [product productIdentifier]);
        }

        for(NSString *invalidProduct in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
            SLLog(@"Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: %@", invalidProduct);
#endif  
        isProductsAvailable = YES;
    } else if ([response.invalidProductIdentifiers count] > 0){
        SLLog(@"MKStoreManager-productsRequest empty results: %@", [response.invalidProductIdentifiers objectAtIndex:0]);
    }
    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(productFetchComplete)])
        [_delegate productFetchComplete];
    [request autorelease];
}
```

Comment: It seems that someone had the same problem. Please look into it if my description isn't clear enough. http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Mar/msg00349.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what somebody told me at the Cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com:

> Are you connecting to the Sandbox
>   environment or production?
>
> I believe you can only connect to
>   Sandbox when launched via Xcode *and*
>   if the app is being 'upgraded' from an
>   App Store version, it won't trigger
>   the Sandbox. At least, that's a tiny
>   bit of IAP voodoo I've witnessed...
>   That means it could cease to be true
>   at any moment, as IAP setup is one
>   sacrificial lamb away from being
>   magic.

I'm not %100 sure about this because I haven't tested yet, but I will let you know as soon as I do.

Comment: Yep - confirmed that you get no products returned when you "upgrade" an app-store install via an Xcode build. Was driving me crazy!

Comment: I came specifically searching for this issue, and this might be my fix. I will comment back later with results. I had an app from the App Store on my iPhone but not on my iPad. Was getting invalidProducts on the iPhone but not iPad, but the app did not exist on the iPad to begin with.